# Console.WriteLine() not working properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010.

It seems that out of nowhere, I can't use `Console.WriteLine()`

For example now I do:

- File -> New project
- Visual C# -> Console Application

Inside the Main method. Everything works fine. This works as expected:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Works!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I add a new class, by clicking Test -> Add -> Class

Inside this new class I can't call `Console.Writeline()` or anything rather.

Visual studio is already not suggesting it, but I ran it just in case and so that I could share the error and it gave me:

```
Error   1   El token '(' no es válido en una clase, un struct o una declaración de miembro de interfaz  c:\users\trufa\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Test\Test\Class1.cs    10  26  Test
```

The translation would be:

```
The token "(" is not valid in a class, a struct, or interface member declaration...
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

It really seamed to happen out of nowhere.

<sub>I didn't think the question was for superuser but let me know if you think otherwise.</sub>

EDIT, Full code as is:

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Works!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Class1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{

    class Class1
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Works!");//this one gives me the error
    }
}
```

Just in case:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the entire code for your new class?

Comment: Could you share your class code?

Comment: Do you have any methods inside this class? You can't just put method calls inside a `class` body.

Comment: Does it happens if you just add another regular class? (instead of a test class)

Comment: can you post the code of the class, you can't call Console.Writeline() in? Sounds to me, as if you are trying to put your code directly into the class and not into one of the methods!?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you typed the code directly into the class rather than placing in a method e.g?

```
public class Class1
{
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Gives me the error

> Error 32  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   ...\Class1.cs   10  21  ConsoleTester

**EDIT**

Place the call inside a method, then it will compile. You can't place calls like that directly in the class itself.

```
public class Class1
{
   public void Test()
   {
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the question exactly, unless I'm misunderstanding you, that is what I'm doing.

Comment: Wow, that was it. Can I as why, or even better a reference to what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: It is basic Object Oriented programming. All objects (instances of a class) have methods. Within the methods you place your logical code. In this case you tried to place a call to a static method 'Console.WriteLine()' when it was expecting a method/property declaration.

Comment: Oh my... I did the same mistake. This is because of a namespace! You have no name space block in many languages, ex. Java of Kotlin, and your mind is trying to convince you that your first block is class and second is a method, while in C# first is name space, second class and you must create third one for actual function.